# Call a bean method with the downloaded filename after file download using sftp outbound gateway

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-el, spring-integration-sftp

I am using `int-sftp:outbound-gateway` to download remote files. File download is working. I need to call another method after file is downloaded  for both success as well as failure. In that method I need status (success or failure) and name of the file that was requested to be downloaded. Then from that method I will initiate a post download flow depending on the status like - moving file to different location, notifying the user, sending email, etc.

I have used `AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor` to call my own method defined in `MyAfterReturningAdvice` which implements `AfterReturningAdvice` interface. With this my method to initiate the post download flow. It does execute and I do get filename in GenericMessage's payload. My question is, do we have a better way to implement this flow.

I tried using `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`'s onSuccessExpression but from that I cannot call another method. All I can do is manipulate the inputMessage(GenericMessage instance).

In future sprints I will have compare checksum of downloaded file with expected checksum and re-download file for a fixed number of times if there is checksum mismatch. As soon as checksum matches I again need to call post download flow. If the download fails even at last retry, then I need to call another flow (send email, update db, notify user of failure,etc.)
I am asking this question just to make sure that my current implementation fits overall requirements.

```
<int:gateway id="downloadGateway" service-interface="com.rizwan.test.sftp_outbound_gateway.DownloadRemoteFileGateway"
    default-request-channel="toGet"/>

<bean id="myAfterAdvice" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="com.rizwan.test.sftp_outbound_gateway.MyAfterReturningAdvice">
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<int-sftp:outbound-gateway id="gatewayGet"
    local-directory="C:\sftp-outbound-gateway"
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    request-channel="toGet"
    remote-directory="/si.sftp.sample"
    command="get"
    command-options="-P"
    expression="payload"
    auto-create-local-directory="true">
    <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="myAfterAdvice" />
    </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-sftp:outbound-gateway>


public class MyAfterReturningAdvice implements AfterReturningAdvice {

    @Override
    public void afterReturning(Object returnValue, Method method, Object[] args, Object target) throws Throwable {
        //update db, send email, notify user.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.onSuccessExpression()` is the best choice for you. Its `EvaluationContext` is `BeanFactory`-aware, therefore you definitely can call any bean from that expression. The `Message` provided there as a root object is a good candidate to get an information about a downloaded file.

So, this is what you can do there:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
    <property name="onSuccessExpressionString" value="@myBean.myMethod(#root)"/>
</bean>
```

The same you can do with the `onFailureExpression`.

On the other hand you may even don't need to worry about the bean access from the expression. The `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` has `successChannel` and `failureChannel` options. So, the message with the result can be send there and some `<service-activator>` with your bean can handle a message on that channel.

Comment: thanks Artem, I was stuck for a long time in the proper syntax to use in onSuccessExpression. Really appreciate it.